# getting gmail contacts using oAuth

Tags: google-plus

I have an application that allows Google+ sign-in for users. I would like to get the user's gmail contacts. Can I use the same access token to get gmail contacts as well?

My confusion is around gmail contacts vs Google+ contacts. Are these two different things?

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are different. Contacts are people who have sent emails to or added to contacts in Gmail and can be accessed through [this API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/). Google+ contacts are people/pages you follow/friend on Google+ and can be access using [this API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list). There will generally be some overlap between the two though.